# Given the commutator of two operator,how to relate their eigenvectors?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

Given **A** and **B** is two linear, self-adjoint operators of a (separable) Hilbert space. Now if commutator of **A** and **B** is known, the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of **A** and **B** is known as well. Is there any relation between eigenvectors of **A** and **B** ?

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but I'm going to guess no. If two operators don't commute, there's no reason to expect them to have the same eigenvectors, so I can't see how you would develop a relationship between the eigenvalues. But like I said, that's just my very untrained intuition.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to think of the "limit case" that you want. Ie: if $A$ and $B$ commute and you know the spectra of $A$. Can you know the spectra of $B$? The answer is no (just take diagonal operators). On the other hand, the eigenspace decompositions of commuting operator are compatible, so it is reasonable to think that the eigenspaces of $A$ would be close to those of $B$ is they almost commute.

Comment: Btw, there is a case in which you can say something about the spectra of $B$ from the spectra of $A$ and the commutator $[A,B]$. When $[A,B]$ is in the span of $1$, $A$ and $B$. This is because, in that case, the multiplication law in the $C^\ast$ algebra generated by $A$ and $B$ would be completely determined.

Comment: The only thing you may be sure of is that, since *A* and *B* are not simultaneously diagonalizable, they cannot possibly share all their eigenvectors. Try it with a 3x3 example to reassure yourself.